# How do I get the default system locale in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I want to get the default system locale in Windows 7, I figured out that the login screen uses this. So I want to start one application during system startup, before the login screen appear. So that the result I get is user independent. Please let me know if any have pointers...

Comment: Can't you just log which user is logged in and save your data for that given user? Or store the data in their profile folder?

Comment: My application must return me System default locale during startup.. So i need the application to run on startup.

Comment: It would be added to the proper HKLM registry run key...http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/AdminTips/Miscellaneous/WindowsProgramStartupLocations.html

Answer (score 5):

You don't necessarily need to run this from the login screen, an example:

```
systeminfo /FO LIST | find "System Locale"
```

A Developer alternative can be found here: [MSDN - GetSystemDefaultLocaleName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318122.aspx)

This result will be user independent!

**Don't use a service** just to get that value, services are meant to be long-running tasks.

**Don't use credential providers** either, they are used as authentication methods.

Answer (score 3):

I do know Windows 7 introduces Trigger Startup Services which allows you to start services without requiring a user to log into the console.  Hopefully this might point you in the right direction:

http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/10/26/windows7-trigger-start-services-part-1-introduction.aspx